# Windows Server 2012 R2 Task Scheduler access denied (0x80070005), but command works manually in shell

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, permissions, batch-file

I have the following problem. On our Windows Server 2012 R2 is a scheduled task which calls a batch file, which in return calls vb scripts.

Those scripts just download 5 pictures and stores them into a folder under a specified name. If I call the bat directly via command line, it works like a charm but with the scheduler I get following information.

It saves the files in the same partition where the script is located. Just in another folder where the user also has access, because he is added to the admin group.

```
Event Information: Event-ID: 201  ResultCode 2147943645 successfully completed
```

The ResultCode seems to match the following access denied message.

```
Result of the last execution: Access denied 0x80070005
```

My researches lead me to try some config changes.

- Run the task in the Schedule with highes rivileges -> same error
- Change the security for %windir%/system32/cmd.exe -> user already in 
  the admin group
- Remove " from start in -> there is nothing, also    adding the
  folder, where the script is located doesn't change    anything

Thank you in advance for any hint, question, information to this problem.

Comment: Check this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187292/issue-with-task-scheduler-launching-a-task

Answer (score 0):

I think that should check [Task Security Context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152(v=ws.11).aspx) of your schedulled task.

Do you have store user's password in the task?

The error can be caused by lack of network access.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I'm new at the company and they just copied the files from a 2003 Server onto a 2012r2 Server and added the task like in the old Server. Also I worked with Linux in the past and the persons knew this. Therefore I'm really dumb when i comes to Windows Securtiy Stuff. We think it coul dbe a problem with the UAC of the Server

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to grant the "Log on as batch job" system privilege to the service account that you are using to run the scheduled task.

(You are not running the scheduled task with your own personal credentials, right?)

From TechNet's description:

> Allows a user to be logged on by means of a batch-queue facility. For
>   example, when a user submits a job by means of the task scheduler, the
>   task scheduler logs that user on as a batch user rather than as an
>   interactive user.
>
> By default, only the LocalSystem account has the privilege to be
>   logged on as a batch job.

This can be set in a domain GPO or in a local GPO, both in the following location:

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment
```

To confirm the source of the "Access denied" failure, you should check the Windows Security log in Event Viewer. Filter the log to only show Audit Failures, and then search for the last time that you attempted to run your scheduled task.

Comment: The Adminstration-Group is added there and the User, I'm working with, is in the Administation-Group